# Publish or Deploy Web api project in IIS using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have read properly all the related questions, but unfortunately no answer helped me.

I have created an empty web API on VS 2017  and created all the methods I want in the HomeController and had my web api tested locally, it succeeded.

Now I want to publish it to the server IIS. Let us suppose that the server will be like this **111.118.1.100**

I tried to publish the website to the folder and uploaded the published files to the root of my server, but when I tried to invoke the methods as the way I used to do locally, it did not work

locally:
localhost:33337/api/home/getSections

OnServer:

111.118.1.100/WebSiteFolder/api/home/getSections

but on the server did not work.

appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried the API once published, directly on the server?

Comment: hello @Manta. Actually, it is the first time for me to create Web API I am a PHP guy, but I had to. so now how can I publish it on the server directly. I tried to upload the whole source code to the server and convert it to website but that did not help

Comment: @NahamAl-Zuhairi Do you have a website created in IIS which is mapped to the folder where you are uploading the published files? Publishing a website is recommended and there is no need to upload the source code. Either you need a new website in IIS or a new application created under `Default website`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood. I published my web api and uploaded folder of all published files to the root of the host but now I do not now how to access the methods in the controller as I used to do locally

Comment: @NahamAl-Zuhairi, what is the error are you getting when you try to access the API? Can you share screenshot of the IIS from your server? It should have the website node expanded showing your newly hosted app and also the port binding.

Comment: At this step, we don't know what you have already done. It could be deploy problem or server problem. The first thing you can do is to test the configuration of the server. What you can do is to place a simple `Index.html` page at the root of the server and try to access it.

Comment: @NahamAl-Zuhain maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53848226) may help you.