# ASP.NET Web API does not work when publish it in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have built an ASP.NET Web API when I run or brows it from Visual Studio its work fine, but when I host it in IIS and try to browse it its not work and give me the following error:

> HTTP 400 error It’s not you, it’s this link (it appears to be broken)

here where i publish my web service 
[image]

the API method is

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("findall")]
    public HttpResponseMessage findAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mde.Products.ToList()));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            return response;

        }
        catch
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

I send the following request to it :

```
http://localhost:9810/api/product/findall
```

how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Could you provide the request that fails and the API method that you expect to handle the request? Also, setting `customErrors="Off"` might sometimes give you more details about the error.

Comment: @ImantasSankalas  I edited the post and provided it with information you ask .

Comment: Instead of suppressing the exception with `catch` (all), you might want to log or temporarily output the exception that causes you to respond with `BadRequest`. That is `catch (Exception e) { /* do something with the "e" */ }`. As a starting point, I would simply remove the try-catch block and let the server output the exception details.

Comment: Is the port the right one? It seems that it must be "80" in your request.

Comment: @Imantas thank you very much ... your comment help me to find the problem wich is i should add the IIS user to the logins in the sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on screenshot, you have deployed your application as virtual app on the Default Site. And **/myserver** is defined as virtual path. It means that your API root URL would be:

```
http://localhost:{IIS_PORT}/myserver/{YOUR_APP_ROUTES}
```

For default website port is 80; If URL from your post (http://localhost:9810/api/product/findall) is working on IIS-express correctly, try to invoke this URL for your IIS deployment:

```
http://localhost/myserver/api/product/findall
```

Answer (score 0):

Excute this command in command prompt

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

for me its solved the issue